# splitActionBarWhenNarrow for api 17 not showing bottom menu

Tags: android

I´m using Action Bar Sherlock for a project which runs fine on 2 emulators with API level 10 and 15.

But the split action bar is not shown on a API 17 emulator.

I´m using 8 as min sdk version, and 19 as target sdk version.

The only clue I have are this lines in logcat:

> 955-955/? W/dalvikvm﹕ method Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout;.drawDividersHorizontal incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
>
> 955-955/? W/dalvikvm﹕ method Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout;.drawDividersVertical incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
>
> 955-955/? W/dalvikvm﹕ method Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout;.drawHorizontalDivider incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
>
> 955-955/? W/dalvikvm﹕ method Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout;.drawVerticalDivider incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;

I didn´t found anything about it unfortunately.
Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the Dalvik runtime that incorrectly allowed to override package-private methods. This bug was fixed in recent versions of Android and in the ART runtime.

ActionBarSherlock relies on a hack that exploits this bug. Because ABS is no longer maintained, I strongly suggest that you migrate to ActionBarCompat by Google instead. It is functionnaly equivalent and the usage is very similar.